# How do I fix my "No valid exports main found" compile error?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to compile the files using

npm start

but it doesn't works.

In my chrome and terminal, it says like this way.

Failed to compile
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Jiwoo\Desktop\movie_app_2020\node_modules\colorette'

I tried to delete folder [node_modules] and typing "npm i" but it doesn't works too.

How can I fix my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade node.js and also remove create-react-app globally by using below command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and using:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but it still doesn't work. Do you know another solution?

Comment: what is the version of your node.js

Comment: it's version is 13.5.0

Comment: increase its version to 14.5

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 7 and the latest working Node version is 13.6. Therefore to make it run the only option is to downgrade autoprefixer: `npm i autoprefixer@9.8.0`
Downgrading `colorette` module to 1.2.0 didn't help.
The ultimate solution is to upgrade Node, however, it's not possible on Windows 7. Alternatively, one can try to compile it on a VM or with a docker image that supports Node 14+.

Answer (score -1):

For windowss 7 user who are using any of the 12+ version just download the last 13 version which is v13.14.0. Before installing this version make sure to uninstall the previous version installed.
Here's the download [link](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.14.0/)

Download the .msi file instead of exe file

Hope it will work
Thanks